# Can I provide non-admin users access to Azure SQL Server?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, ssms

**Objective:**

I am trying to configure a Azure SQL Server so that all users in an Azure Active Directory group can access the server and view/use any database on the server. Everyone will be using SSMS to connect to the server.

**Attempted Solution & Problem:**

I have been able to successfully grant access to a AAD Group only if I make the user group an admin of the server.

I want the AAD Group to be "Contributors" of the server. When I try this and then try connecting to Azure SQL Server, I get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlEm9.png)

Lastly, authentication will be based on "Azure Active Directory - Password" in SSMS.

Comment: When you asked your question, you were told *"Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)."* Please follow the instructions when posting your questions, as otherwise you are likely to receive down and/or close votes; meaning your question is far less likely to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you create the group on Azure-SQL.

```
CREATE USER <Azure_AD_principal_name> FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

Once you have the group created on the database, please make sure the SID of the group matches the SID on Azure AD. Please get the SID of the group on Azure SQL:

```
SELECT
    DP.name
    ,DP.principal_id
    ,DP.type
    ,DP.type_desc
    ,DP.SID
    ,OBJECTID = CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, DP.SID)
FROM SYS.database_principals DP
WHERE DP.type IN ('S','X','E')
```

[image]

Go to Azure AD and make sure is the same SID.

[image]

If they are not the same, drop the group and recreate it.

Comment: I followed all of your steps. The AD group is added to the SQL server and I confirmed the ObjectID in SQL matches the ID in AD. 

The AD group has the permission of a "Contributor". I am still getting the same error.

I made sure my IP is whitelisted as well. Same error.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: i was able to add individual users to the SQL server. There seems to be an issue with authenticating the user as a member of the group

Comment: Limitations for AD Groups are just 2 as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-azure-ad-only-authentication?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-cli#limitations-for-azure-ad-only-authentication-in-sql-database